# Get parent dir, grandparent dir and so on in gnu make?

Tags: gnu-make

I have a variable path, for example this path from $(shell pwd):

```
C:\a\b\c\d\e\f
```

what i want to get is this and save it in a variable:

```
C:\a\b\c\d\e
C:\a\b\c\d
C:\a\b\c
C:\a\b
C:\a
C:\
```

how to do it in gnu make? And how to stop if there is no more parent (reached C:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to switch into posix path mode.
No appologgies.
Life is too short to mess around with windows paths when cygwin is available.
(I will note though that `$(dir)` recognises backslashes.)

So, a function.

You just spit out the argument,
and then call the function again but this time with the last path component snipped off.
Something like

```
parents = $1 $(call parents,$(dir $1))
```

First problem:
`$(dir a/b/c/d)` returns `a/b/c/`.
Fine,
except that `$(dir /a/b/c/)` just gives you `a/b/c/` again.
You need to strip that final slash before the call:

```
parents = $1 $(call parents,$(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $1)))
```

OK.
Problem now is this recursive call never terminates the sequence.

We need to stop calling `parents` once `$1` has no slashes in it.
Several methods come to mind.
One way is to transliterate `/` into 
 (that's the job of `$(subst …)`),
then stop if the resulting number of words (`$(words …)`) is 1 (`$(filter …)`):

```
parents = \
  $1 \
  $(if $(filter-out,1,$(words $(subst /, ,$1))), \
    $(call parents,$(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $1))))
```

(Hope I've got that nesting right.) Giving:

```
$ cat Makefile
parents = \
  $1 \
  $(if $(filter-out 1,$(words $(subst /, ,$1))), \
    $(call parents,$(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $1))))

$(error [$(call parents,/a/b/c/d/e/f)])


$ make
Makefile:6: *** [/a/b/c/d/e/f  /a/b/c/d/e  /a/b/c/d  /a/b/c  /a/b  /a ].  Stop.
```

:-)

<sub>Footnote: Dunno what you are trying to achieve,
but I reckon there is probably a more *make*-like way of doing it!</sub>